# How to make user data private so only user who owns/created data can see it?

Tags: backend, basic-authentication, vapor

Can somebody tell me what I need to use to make user data private that only authenticated user can see their own data. What should I implement to my code ?

I have already basic authentication and I have authorized users but the problem is that all data is available to all authenticated users who have logged in. I'm using PostgreSQL and Vapor 3 and a newbie with backend.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a vary broad question. Can you give an example of what you mean by 'data' - is it static data, such as image files or is it from a database? Is all the private data to be accessed by the individual user or are there hierarchies?

Comment: Hei Nick! By data I mean that user have answered personal questions and those answers and results will be saved into database. Then later user can go and watch their own answers but not others. There are no hierarhies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have implemented basic authorisation and used a standard Vapor User model, then you will have a unique id for each authorised user. You then just need to add this as a foreign key to each model containing the data you wish to protect. When the user answers the questions, make sure you save the User Id for the current user into the foreign key fields. Then, when you wish to retrieve a user's private data, you just select those records that match the same User Id.

To create the table in the database, put this in the model:

```
extension ExampleModel: Migration
{
    public static func prepare(on connection: MySQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return Database.create(self, on: connection) { builder in
            try addProperties(to: builder)
            builder.reference(from: \.userId, to: \User.id)
        }
    }
}
```

When I create a new (private) record, I pass the current user's Id as a parameter to the init function, thus:

```
init(user:User) throws
{
    createdByUserId = user.id!
    // initialise the remaining fields as well
}
```

To restrict records in a route to just those created by a user, I use:

```
events.get("/")
{
    req -> Future<View> in
    let query = try Event.query()
    query.filter(\.userID == theUserId )            
    // the rest of your route
}
```

Comment: Hope it helped. I see you've asked a second question where you've also thanked the answerer but not 'accepted' the answer either. If you do accept (by clicking on the tick), it shows other users that the answer was useful (and, okay... it gives the answerer reputation points!)

Comment: Hei sorry, I'm still trying to find out how to use this, Learning everyday!